# Incorrect datastore keys in Testbed

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, testing

I'm trying to test an application that runs on App Engine. I'm using [the Testbed framework](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting.html), and so far it works like a charm, except for the following unexpected behaviour:

A test like this would **work just fine** (simplified version without a framework):

```
from google.appengine.ext import db, testbed
testbed = testbed.Testbed()
testbed.activate()
testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()
class Foo(db.Model):
    pass

# now for the tests:
key = Foo().put()
assert key == db.Key.from_path('Foo', key.id())
assert Foo.all(keys_only=True).get() == db.Key.from_path('Foo', key.id())
assert db.get(db.Key.from_path('Foo', key.id()))  # fails!

testbed.deactivate()
```

However, the following would **fail** (again, simplified version):

```
from google.appengine.ext import db, testbed
testbed = testbed.Testbed()
testbed.activate()
testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()
from myapp.models import Foo

# now for the tests:
key = Foo().put()
assert key == db.Key.from_path('Foo', key.id())  # fails!
assert Foo.all(keys_only=True).get() == db.Key.from_path('Foo', key.id())  # fails!
assert db.get(db.Key.from_path('Foo', key.id()))  # fails!

# however, the following will succeed:
assert key == db.Key.from_path('Model', key.id())
assert Foo.all(keys_only=True).get() == db.Key.from_path('Model', key.id()) 
assert db.get(key)

testbed.deactivate()
```

Where does the model name disappear during the tests? And how come it only happens with imported modules?

**EDIT:**

Thanks [proppy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/656408/proppy), typos fixed.

[Nick Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12030/nick-johnson), let me try to explain it better.

When I query a result from the `testbed` datastore stub, I get an entity, just like I'd expect. But when I call the `.key()` method on that entity, I get things like `datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Model', 1L, _app=u'testbed-test')`, while `Model` is clearly not the correct kind of my entity.

When I try to get the entity for that key (`datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Model', 1L, _app=u'testbed-test')`), it works just fine.

The problem is, when I only know the `id` of a datastore entity, and I try to construct the key manually, using `db.Key.from_path(...)`.

For example, the kind should be `User`, so I can construct the key using `db.Key.from_path('User', 1)`. But I cannot get an entity from the datastore using that key. I can, however, using `db.Key.from_path('Model', 1)`, but, as I said, `Model` is not the correct datastore kind.

In other words:

```
from myapp.models import User
User(email='dont@write.us').kind()  # returns 'Model', not 'User'!
```

Note that this unexpected behaviour does not occur in production or in the dev server, only when using `testbed`, and only when the `db.Model` subclass is defined in my application code (i.e. not in the test cases themselves).

I am not using Django, I'm using Pyramid with traversal, but the unit tests I'm running here do not call any framework-specific code.

Note that <strike>I haven't tried this with `ndb` yet</strike> the same thing happens with `ndb` as well..

**Edit 2:**

Apparently I haven't noticed that all of my classes were subclasses of a `google.appengine.ext.db.polymodel.PolyModel` subclass, so the keys were in fact correctly set as `Model`, because the kind is `Model` on all `PolyModel` subclasses.

Comment: I believe there is a typo in your code s/Triu/True/g

Comment: So what is `key` in this case? It's hard to diagnose without any additional information. And are you using Django?

Comment: @AttilaOláh So the real problem appears to be that testbed does not handle polymodel properly. Are you able to produce a minimal test that reproduces the issues without importing your code?

Comment: Sounds to me like there is no bug here, right?

Comment: @gvanrossum is right, there's no bug here. I expected `PolyModel` subclasses to have the same kind name as the bottom-most subclass name, but it is not the case. All `PolyModel` subclasses have the kind name `Model`. Which seems a bit counter-intuitive to me, but not a bug. @NickJohnson I was mistaken, `testbed` handles everything properly, I just failed to notice that due to my frustration.

Comment: Great. Note that in NDB's polymodel, the kind name *is* that of the bottom-most (depending on your POV :-) subclass. Hopefully that will be more intuitive (though it is less compatible).

Comment: @gvanrossum that's not what I have experienced so far, at least not with `ndb 0.9.5`. The kind name remained `Model`. Is this change new in `0.9.6`?

Comment: Um, the only way I can explain that is if your base class (the one that directly derives from PolyModel) is actually named Model. Neither NDB nor db defaults to Model for the kind name when you define a subclass. I can't explain how testbed would affect this either. If you still have questions please post the actual source code that causes the kind to be set to Model.

Comment: @gvanrossum I feel so stupid now; checked out that version of the code, it turns out my base class was indeed called "Model". So that pretty much solves the mystery. Thank you for taking your time to chase this down - I should have been able to catch this on my own though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, this problem was caused by a file called `migrations.py` that I had in my project, which redefined my models using classes that had different properties. When I was running the tests, `nose` tried to import all available files to post coverage results, which caused the module definition clash, and thus all the confusion.